# dojo using this

Tags: javascript, dojo, this

hello I'm just started to learn dojo, how can I use `this` object? I've created something like  below but I thing its not right

```
var node = dojo.query('.verticalslider')[0];
dojo.connect(node, "onclick", function(){
    var c = dojo.query(this).parent();
    console.log(c);
})
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
// eventlistener is setup on every DOM node with className 'verticalslider'  
dojo.query('.verticalslider').connect("click", function(){

    // this references the clicked DOM node
    var c = this.parentNode

    // parentNode of the clicked DOM node with class 'vertical..'
    console.log(c);
})
```

This is more of a general js question then it is a dojo but for the .connect and .on functions following applies:

dojo.connect is a wrapper for creating eventlistener. normally if you write code like node.foo = function() {} you can only have the one function, as equal sign overrides the existing one. The standard behavior of .connect is that the same scope applies, so 'this' is referencing the object we're listening on. In this case 'node'.

`dj.connect(node, "foo", function() { this == node evaluates to true and arguments[0] == event });`

dojo.hitch (dojo/_base/lang) is a scope attach helper. It works for any event but a timeout/interval hook and will force the function object passed to, say .connect, to run in the given scope as such: dojo.hitch(scope, functor).

`dj.connect(node, "bar", dj.hitch(dojo.doc(), function() { this == window.document evals true }));`

As far as dojo.query goes, it will return you with a NodeList. A list cannot have a single parent, so your dojo.query(node).parent() is wrong. the correct use of .query is to pass a selector as your first use of it. Like so:

```
dj.query(
  /* String */ "CSS Selector",
  /* Optional DOM node, defaults to body */ contextNode
)   // => dojo.NodeList
```

see [NodeList docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/NodeList.html)

Answer (score 0):

The above code mentioned is a straight way through, but if you need the context of this inside any function/ callback , use dojo.hitch (<1.7) or lang.hitch (1.7+). It passes the context of this inside the function.

For Ex:

```
var myObj = {
  foo: "bar"
};
var func = dojo.hitch(myObj, function(){
  console.log(this.foo);
});
```

Here this inside the function refers to the context of the object myObj.

Another Fixed code for you can be:

```
var node = dojo.query('.verticalslider')[0];
dojo.connect(node, "onclick", dojo.hitch(this,function(){
    var c = dojo.query(this).parent(); // here this will be having the outside context .
    console.log(c);
}))
```